# How github auto updating comments work?

Tags: django, html, github

As mentioned here

https://github.com/blog/1174-auto-updating-comments

What is the technology behind this? If I've to add this feature in a Django powered web app, what should I use and study?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at network tab it looks like they (at least with chrome) are using HTML5 Server Sent Events.

So practically the browser subscribes to a event stream and the web server just sends messages back.

I am not an expert but I guess on the server side you need to be able to keep an open connection that streams the events to the client.

I found an implementation of SSE for python here: https://github.com/niwibe/sse and a django implementation on top of that: https://github.com/niwibe/django-sse

I did not use them (yet) on any production so I suggest them only as study / poc material :)